# c++ struct reference types

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class called IAckHandler

```
class IAckHandler {
public:
    virtual ~IAckHandler();

    virtual void handleAck(long messageType, bool ackrcvd, uint8_t ackByte) = 0;
private:

};
```

The intended use is for other classes to inherit, so this is basically a "interface" class.

I am using message queues to submit requests to a polling thread(uart comm) and want to pass in an IAckHandler into the message queue message.
The struct is like so:

```
struct reqmsg
    {
        long int mtype;
        void (*reqHandler)(MasterRadioComm*, uint8_t*);
        IAckHandler* ackHandler;
        unsigned char mtext[NUM_INDICES];
    };
```

Here is the function to submit to message queue

```
void Uartcom::req_doSomething(IAckHandler& ackHandler)
{
    struct reqmsg req;
    if(ackHandler == NULL) req.ackHandler = this;
    else req.ackHandler = ackHandler;
    msgsnd(m_msgQueueKey, &req, sizeof(struct reqmsg) - sizeof(long), 0);
}
```

But when I pass in a reference to an IAckHandler, I get `cannot convert ‘IAckHandler’ to ‘IAckHandler*’ in assignment.`

Can I call req_doSomething(this) from another class that inherits IAckHandler?

Comment: You don't need to say `struct` in C++. `reqmsg req;` and `sizeof(reqmsg)` do just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be lacking some basic pointers and references knowledge. For the `req_doSomething` given in the example, `&ref` will give you a pointer to the referred object so it should be

```
else req.ackHandler = &ackHandler;
```

and to get a reference from a pointer, you derreference it with `*ptr` so the call would be

```
req_doSomething(*this);
```

...or just drop the reference and work entirely with pointers.

**Update:** As others have pointed out, a reference cannot be NULL.

Comment: ah ok..so "this" is a pointer, not a reference type. When I use "this" do I need to do this-> or this.?

Comment: @user623879: You need to use `this->`

Comment: Since we are talking reference type here, the comparision is between the special literal `0` and an object of type `IAckHandler&`. Assuming that it is another mistake and `if(&ackHandler == NULL)` was the original intention, it has to be noted, that `&ackHandler` can indeed compare equal to `0`! Take the example function `void test(int& a) { cout << &a << endl; }` and call it like this: `test(*(int*)0)`.

Comment: If `IAckHandler` were comparable with `0`, then the comparison would be well formed. Given the definition of `IAckHandler`, such comparison is not included, and while it could be make valid by 3rd types or conversions I assume the OP has confused references with pointers. Passing `*(int*)0` to a type expecting a reference to `int` is actually not allowed by the standard.

Comment: null references may not be allowed by the standard, but at all compilers i have tested above program fragment with, compile and run it perfectly fine.

Comment: They sure do, but that doesn't make it legal C++; so its more of a lucky implementation detail than a language feature.

Comment: Which does not help if the OP does not feel confident that the callers of his function might abuse this implementation detal ;)

Comment: According to the standard, once you introduce undefined behavior into a program not only the subsequent statements may do whatever they want but also the previous ones as well. As soon as undefined behavior is used, the result of the whole program is undefined according to C++, so if someone actually decides to artificially create a null reference then it should be ready to face the consecuents, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

Change your function declaration to take the argument as a pointer rather than a reference:

```
void Uartcom::req_doSomething(IAckHandler * ackHandler)
                                         ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues with your req_doSomething function:

1. ackHandler is a reference which cannot be NULL.
2. You are trying to assign a reference to a pointer (`req.ackHandler = &ackHandler;` is what you want).

However, it's probably a better idea to do something like this:

```
void Uartcom::req_doSomething(IAckHandler * ackHandler)
{
    struct reqmsg req;
    if(ackHandler == NULL) req.ackHandler = this;
    else req.ackHandler = ackHandler;
    msgsnd(m_msgQueueKey, &req, sizeof(struct reqmsg) - sizeof(long), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It describes exactly what you should do.

just past the object's address to the pointer:

```
req.ackHandler = &ackHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully. The member in the struct is an "IAckHandler*" while the arg received in the setter function in a reference to IAckHandler. What you may want to do is:

```
req.ackHandler = &ackHandler;
```

regards,

Yati Sagade

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you must have declared ackHandler as an IAckHandler* in struct reqmsg.  In C++, reference types (like IAckHandler&), although implemented using pointers, are treated syntactically as if they were embedded objects - basically you need to work with an IAckHandler& as if it were an IAckHandler, not an IAckHandler*.

Therefore, you should be able to fix your code like this:

```
void Uartcom::req_doSomething(IAckHandler& ackHandler)
{
    struct reqmsg req;
    if(ackHandler == NULL) req.ackHandler = this;
    else req.ackHandler = &ackHandler;
    msgsnd(m_msgQueueKey, &req, sizeof(struct reqmsg) - sizeof(long), 0);
}
```